# Question Involving Bonding (VSEPR AND VBT)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, bond, hybridization, vsepr-theory

So basically any chemistry book will tell you about the extent of overlapping in different orbitals.
For formation of sigma bonds, head on overlapping happens. Chemistry textbooks always state that $p-p$ overlap is more effective than $s-s$ overlap. The explanation given is that the s-orbital is spherically symmetric. So it is non directional, while the p-orbital is definitely directional.

However, if we think of hybridised orbitals, $sp$ orbitals are known to form stronger bonds than $sp^2$ and $sp^3$ hybrid orbitals. The explanation given is that the higher percentage of the s-character makes a bond stronger. If that is the case, then shouldn't an $s-s$ overlapping be stronger than a $p-p$ one?

And if $p-p$ overlapping is better than $s-s$ one, shouldn't the hybrid orbitals with higher p character form stronger bonds?

I am kind of confused. I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: I can't think of a lot of bonds where you expect s-s overlap (excluding hybridization). That makes a comparison of strengths  of bonds involving p-p vs s-s overlap difficult. It's always good to support statements by citing a source rather than writing " any chemistry book". In any case I suspect most "proofs" are theoretical in nature.